# OpenCV - image getting blurred when rotating with warpAffine

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm using openCv's `warpAffine()` function to rotate an image with this code-

```
void rotateImage(const Mat &src, Mat &dest, double angle)
{
    cv::Point2f point(src.cols/2, src.rows/2);

    Mat rotationMatrix = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(point, angle, 1.0);

    cv::warpAffine(src, dest, rotationMatrix, cv::Size(src.cols, src.rows));
}
```

It works fine if I rotate the image with some angle multiple of 90 (in degrees) but severly blurs the image with any arbitrary rotation angle.

eg-
the original image

[image]

After rotating by 90 degree multiple times-

[image]

After rotating by 30 degree multiple times-

[image]

So is there any way I can rotate the image by any arbitrary angle and avoid the caused blur?

Comment: This is still an existing problem, and the answer given is not solving it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try to use the flags option to see the result of different interpolation methods:

`INTER_NEAREST` - a nearest-neighbor interpolation

`INTER_LINEAR` - a bilinear interpolation (default)

`INTER_AREA` - resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method.

`INTER_CUBIC` - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood

`INTER_LANCZOS4` - a Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood

For example:

`cv::warpAffine(src, dest, rotationMatrix, cv::Size(src.cols, src.rows),cv::INTER_CUBIC);`

You will always lose some quality though, because of the interpolation. It is better not to do multiple warps on the same image after each other.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll maintain a copy or the original image and apply rotations on it's clone instead of on a single image multiple times.

Also to add- shrinking an image will look best with `CV_INTER_AREA` interpolation and expanding an image will look best with `CV_INTER_CUBIC` or `CV_INTER_LINEAR` (read form OpenCV manual).

Comment: `cv::warpAffine` does not support `INTER_AREA`. It automatically uses `INTER_LINEAR` if called with `INTER_AREA`, see [source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/debe99f1a4cc0ea859b91996613934e361b544b6/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L5585).

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? None of these tags actually work against blurring.

Comment: Because this causes the blurring: "It is better not to do multiple warps on the same image after each other."